# コードフェンスが編集時には反映されているが、通常時には反映されない？

Tags: バグ, デザイン, markdown, 編集

### 不具合事象

[cocos2d-x(v3.14.1)のandroidで、sdkbox::PluginShare::init()時にクラッシュしてしまう](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/35111/cocos2d-xv3-14-1%E3%81%AEandroid%E3%81%A7-sdkboxpluginshareinit%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%86) という質問を見ると「発生している問題・エラーメッセージ」という見出しのすぐ下にコードフェンス用と思われるバッククォートがそのまま表示されていました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

そこで、この不要なバッククォートを削除するため、編集を行おうとすると、編集時のプレビューではこれらのバッククォートは表示されていませんでした。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

### 補足情報 (OS, ブラウザのバージョンなど)

不具合が再現した OS, ブラウザは以下のとおりです。

- Windows 10
- Opera 66.0.3515.115

Answer (score 1):

コードフェンスの内側ではスペース4つのインデントも含まれているので、

- 編集プレビュー時は外側の ```` ``` ```` コードフェンスが効いている状態。
- 通常表示時は内側のスペースによるハイライトが効いている状態 (=外側の ```` ``` ```` がそのまま表示される)

という挙動になってしまっているように見えます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。通常時にはスペースがそのまま残っているので、私も cubick さんの回答された通りの動作になっていると思います。この 2 つの動作のうち、スタック・オーバーフローの Markdown としては、どちらが期待されるものなのでしょうか？